# Electron - how to get an auth token from BrowserWindow to the main Electron App

Tags: javascript, angular, oauth-2.0, electron, openid-connect

I have an Angular Electron app that uses a BrowserWindow to log in using a third-party OpenID Connect Identity Provider.
Additionally, I have my own Backend that implements the OpenID Connect standard.
The backend runs under `localhost:5000`.

**Package versions:**

Angular: 11.1.0
electron: 9.1.0
ngx-electron: 2.2.0

**The Flow is like this:**

- Electron opens a BrowserWindow with `localhost:5000/connect/authorize` as URL (including required query parameters)
- Backend redirects to third-party Identity Provider
- User logs in
- Third Party redirects to Backend with auth info
- Backend redirects to the provided returnUri (Frontend callback)
- BrowserWindow calls the callback function and has the auth token in the URL (as expected)

--> How do I get the auth token from the BrowserWindow to the main Electron app? Actually, I need
the callback function to be called in the main Electron app

Login logic, that is called in the main Electron app:

```js
public login() {
  // Everything in here is called in the main Electron app

  const authWindow = new this.electron.remote.BrowserWindow({
      width: 800, 
      height: 600, 
      show: false, 
      webPreferences: {
        nodeIntegration: false,
        webSecurity: false
      }
    });

    authWindow.loadURL(myAuthurl);
    authWindow.show();
    authWindow.webContents.openDevTools();

    const defaultSession = this.electron.remote.session.defaultSession;

    const { session: { webRequest } } = authWindow.webContents; 

    webRequest.onBeforeRequest(null, async request => {
      console.log(request);
    });

    webRequest.onBeforeRedirect(null, async request => {
      console.log(request); // Callback function never called

    });

    defaultSession.webRequest.onBeforeRequest(null, async request => {
      console.log(request); // Callback function never called
    });

    defaultSession.webRequest.onBeforeRequest(null, request => {
      console.log(request); // Callback function never called
    });


    defaultSession.webRequest.onBeforeRedirect(null, request => {
      console.log(request); // Callback function never called
    });

    authWindow.on('closed', (event) => {
      console.log(event); // Callback function called when the window is closed but with no data
    });
}
```

Callback Logic, called in BrowserWindow (But it's the same Angular app):

```js
// this method is called after successful log in
// here I'm still in the BrowserWindow

public callback()
  // here's the data I need. How do I "send" this data to the main Electron app?
  const hash = window.location.hash;
}
```

Edit:
I tried `ipcRenderer`, but the `on` callback is never triggered:

```js
// executed in the main Electron app
const ipc = this.electron.ipcRenderer;

ipc.on('authtoken', (event, arg) => {
  console.log(arg);
})

ipc.send('authtoken', 'DATA');
```

Any ideas about what I'm missing here? Are there better approaches?

Comment: Have you though about `ipcRenderer`?

Comment: Yes, but I couldn't get it to work.

Comment: So then please [edit] your question and include your `ipcRenderer` approach, stating also what didn't work.

Comment: I've just added a very basic `ipcRenderer` approach. Maybe I'm missing something obvious here?

Comment: Now, the `ipcRenderer.send()` is supposed to be run in the renderer process which intends to send the data to the main process. There, `ipcMain.on()` is responsible for handling the incoming message and doing something with the sent data. Take a look at [Electron's official IPC tutorial](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/tutorial/ipc#pattern-1-renderer-to-main-one-way) as well as [its process architecture](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/tutorial/process-model) -- understanding the model will help you along the way. If you want to, I can create an answer outlining the basics.

Comment: Thank you very much for both links! According to the official IPC tutorial I must use `contextBridge`. Unfortunately, that is `undefined` in my case. It's used in an `electron-main.js`. Following command is used to start the app: `electron dist/electron-main.js`
I don't have a `preload.js` file that is used in the main `BrowserWindow` - I have a feeling that this might be a problem?

Comment: You don't *have* to use `preload.js` but it's recommended. Also, `contextBridge` will only be available in renderer processes. The problem is that you're mixing up your processes and Electron's nomenclature. All scripts make one Electron app, different windows are not different apps. Each app has one main process (with access to NodeJS APIs) and multiple renderer processes (one for each window); there's a clear separation between all process layers. You can use `ipcRenderer.send()` in the page receiving the token and `ipcMain.on()` in the main file creating the initial window.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! I could finally manage to communicate between the main and renderer process. My second issue was, that I opened a BrowserWinow from the renderer process. But I should have opened it from the main process and load the identity provider in there. Please just write a small answer with `ipcMain.on()` and `ipcRenderer.send()`. I will gladly accept it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's important to understand Electron's process model, as it can be quite complicated and challenging to get right upon first use. Thus, I recommend reading [Electron's process model documentation](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/tutorial/process-model) as well as the official [IPC tutorial](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/tutorial/ipc#pattern-1-renderer-to-main-one-way) for communicating between the processes.

In your case, you'll have to send the token from the Renderer process to the Main process where you store it (or do whatever you want to with it). This is done using `ipcRenderer.send()` in the `BrowserWindow` and `ipcMain.on()` in the Main process.

```js
// BrowserWindow doing the authentication stuff
const { ipcRenderer } = require ("electron");

ipcRenderer.send ("authtoken", "DATA");
```

And the counterpart in the Main process:

```js
// Where your imports are
const { ipcMain } = require ("electron");

// ...

ipcMain.on ("authtoken", (event, arg) => {
    // arg will be the data you sent from the auth window
});
```

In case you open the authentication window from within the Main process, I suggest storing a reference to it, say `let authwindow = new BrowserWindow(...)` so you could close it right away upon receiving the token in the Main process using `authwindow.destroy()`.

However, if you don't do this but instead open the window from another `BrowserWindow`, you can still send an event to that first window, given that you have a reference to it in the Main process. For example:

```js
// Main process, where you create the initial window
// Where your imports are
const { ipcMain } = require ("electron");

// ...
let mainWindow = new BrowserWindow (/* ... */);

ipcMain.on ("authtoken", (event, arg) => {
    // arg will be the data you sent from the auth window
    mainWindow.webContents.send ("close-auth");
});
```

And receive this event in the main window and close the auth window:

```js
// Main window
const { ipcRenderer } = require ("electron");

public login() {
  // Everything in here is called in the main Electron app

  const authWindow = new this.electron.remote.BrowserWindow({
      width: 800, 
      height: 600, 
      show: false, 
      webPreferences: {
        nodeIntegration: false,
        webSecurity: false
      }
    });

    authWindow.loadURL(myAuthurl);
    authWindow.show();
    authWindow.webContents.openDevTools();

    const defaultSession = this.electron.remote.session.defaultSession;

    ipcRenderer.once ("close-auth", (event, arg) => { authWindow.destroy (); });
}
```

(`#once()` will cause subsequent signals to be ignored if the callback function already ran once. If `login()` is called again, this will be registered again and work as expected, but if we had used `#on()` we would grow the number of registered listeners with every function call. `#once()` is also available on `ipcMain` but shouldn't be needed often.)

One last quick note: `remote` is deprecated and thus I suggest to open the authentication window from the Main process, removing `remote` and do all the stuff that would have required `remote` from the Main process, communicating with the different `BrowserWindows` via IPC like I showed you here.

Also, I suggest not to rename Electron packages upon import; if you call the IPC package `ipc` in all process contexts, you will be confused sooner or later. If you keep `ipcMain` and `ipcRenderer` it should be immediately clear in which kind of process you are, should you choose to refactor your code later on.

Comment: Thank you so much for your detailed explanations! Everything's working smoothly now.